Order of date biblatex
I am using biblatex to cite a news report in APA. Everything is working except the detail that the date in the reference is Month day, year. And I would like Year, Month day. Any ideas??
This is my main code to call the package
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

And this is the bibliography
@online{Cooperativa2024,
 author = "Cooperativa",
 year = "2024",
date = {2024-04-28},
entrysubtype = {newspaper},
 title = "Universidad Austral eval\'ua el despido de unos 300 docentes",
 journal = "Cooperativa",
 url = {https://cooperativa.cl/noticias/pais/educacion/universidades/universidad-austral-evalua-el-despido-de-unos-300-docentes/2024-04-15/131029.html},
}



Welcome to TeX.se. Maybe just use the actual apa style instead of generic authoryear style?  This will format the date correctly according to APA7 guidelines.

You are right!! thanks!!

If you use the actual apa style, then the date will be formatted correctly.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % recommended
\usepackage[english]{babel} % recommended (or with an appropriate language)
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\citet{itzhaki}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}


